# python gRPC error: "error": "13 INTERNAL: Failed to serialize response!" when trying to return a repeated message instead of stream in a List Request

Tags: python, django, grpc, django-serializer, grpc-python

I have django REST API that I am trying to convert into gRPC. I followed the [Django grpc framework guide](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest) and created the following files:

###### models.py

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    Org_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Number_of_emp = models.IntegerField()
```

###### org.proto

```
package org;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service OrganizationController {
    rpc List(OrganizationListRequest) returns (Organizations) {}
    rpc Create(Organization) returns (Organization) {}
    rpc Retrieve(OrganizationRetrieveRequest) returns (Organization) {}
    rpc Update(Organization) returns (Organization) {}
    rpc Destroy(Organization) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}

message Organization {
    string Org_name = 1;
    string Address = 2;
    string Description = 3;
    int32 Number_of_emp = 4;
}

message OrganizationListRequest {
}

message OrganizationRetrieveRequest {
    string Org_name = 1;
}

message Organizations {
    repeated Organization organization = 1;
}
```

**Note that Organizations is a message declared in org.proto to return a List or an array of objects**

###### services.py

```
class OrganizationService(generics.ModelService):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializerProto
```

###### serializers.py

```
class OrganizationSerializerProto(proto_serializers.ModelProtoSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        proto_class = org_pb2.Organization
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Problem** I want to make a request using the `rpc List(OrganizationListRequest) returns (Organizations) {}` to fetch a list of all the organization in the database. However, whenever I make a call to the rpc, I get the following error:
[request error: "error": "13 INTERNAL: Failed to serialize response!"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TIh6.png) (I use the BloomRPC gui client to make the request)

However, If I change 
 `rpc List(OrganizationListRequest) returns (Organizations) {}` to  
 `rpc List(OrganizationListRequest) returns (stream Organization) {}`
the request returns works fine and I get a stream of response of containing allobjects. I do not want to return data in streams, I want it to return an array of objects, but using `message Organizations {repeated Organization organization = 1;}` throws the above error.
Am I making a mistake? I searched everywhere but I couldn't find this error. Or is it not possible to make an RPC call like this?

Answer (score 5):

This is a server-side proto codec error. It usually happen because of:

1. Inconsistent generated proto library between client/server;
2. Type mismatch message (like sent `Organizations` instead of `Organization`).

gRPC Python will log the exception that is causing the `Failed to serialize response!` error. You can enable Python logging explicitly via `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`. Here is the link to the logging line:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/bed585bdcb5cbbbfb407b4e869665d405b04adca/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_common.py#L88

If after above examination, the error still persist, can you create a reproduce case and send to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues?